# Build links with SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have around 40,000 links to enter into a database. The links follow a pretty standard format and I was wondering if I could accomplish this via some SQL queries? The field in my database contains a number and I want to build the URL around that number...

example...

123

I want the end result to be...

http://site.com/uni-123-uni

Where you see UNI, that is a unique set of characters. So can I do a prefix and suffix on all the values contained in that particular field? Sending "http://site.com/uni-" as a prefix to the current data, and then sending "-uni" as a suffix to that data?

Or would I be better off creating two more fields in my database, one that I could drop the prefix into, and one for the suffix, and then combine those three fields into the existing field?

Comment: do you want to update all links to same prefix and suffix?

Comment: no there will be 217 different prefixes across 10,000 records, and 3 different suffixes

Comment: How do you identify which prefix and suffix to use for given links

Comment: I have 4 fields that will contain links, depending on which field I am in....will determine the suffix. The prefix will depend on another field called "category_id". I was just going to use excel to build 217 SQL queries, and then run them all to give each field the correct prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) is the way to go.

```
SELECT CONCAT('http://site.com/uni-', number, '-uni') as url FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in T-SQL with [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
SELECT 'http://site.com/uni-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), [MyColumn]) + '-uni'
FROM   [MyTable]
```

Or

```
SELECT 'http://site.com/uni-' + CAST([MyColumn] AS VARCHAR(30)) + '-uni'
FROM   [MyTable]
```

If your prefixes / suffixed need to be based on some variable / parameter:

```
SELECT @prefix + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), [MyColumn]) + @suffix
FROM   [MyTable]
```